# Grouping of nested selectors (headings) (CSS)

Tags: css, grouping

is there any way to group e.g. all heading selectors that are part of some `<div>` element and get them any parameter in short ? I mean something like this:

```
#content h1, #content h2, #content h3, #content h4, #content h5 { color: green }
```

in short:

```
#content h1-h5 { color: green }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to get this functionality.

Example of nesting in LESS:

```
#content {
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
        color: #0f0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for all solutions, I'll take a closer look on these css extensions, seem very handy for variables too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should make a class that you include in each of those elements.  I would recommend doing something like `.green`.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to support only modern browser (webkit and gecko) you may use `:any` pseudoclass

```
#content :any(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {
   color: green;
}
```

see the [reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aany) for the usage with vendor prefixes, but consider that this solution might have some performance penalties:

> Bug 561154 tracks an issue with Gecko where the specificity of :-moz-any() is incorrect. The current (as of Firefox 12) implementation puts :-moz-any() in the category of universal rules, meaning using it as the rightmost selector will be slower than using an ID, class, or tag as the rightmost selector.

Otherwise, for a wider support and better mantainability, use a CSS preprocessor, like others have suggested

Comment: Interesting, haven't heard of this one!